error : Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model
I simply want to wrap the model as a keras layer but it simply is not happening ans keeps showing this error to me, i don't know if it's the keras or tensorflow version but i don't want to change them so is there an alternative?
This is the code I used:
mobilenet_v2 ="https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/classification/4"

classifier_model = mobilenet_v2

IMAGE_SHAPE = (224, 224)

classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(classifier_model, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,))
])

and this is the complete error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 3
      1 IMAGE_SHAPE = (224, 224)
----> 3 classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
      4     hub.KerasLayer(classifier_model, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,))
      5 ])

File ~\Desktop\TFproj\tfvenv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py:73, in Sequential.__init__(self, layers, trainable, name)
     71 if layers:
     72     for layer in layers:
---> 73         self.add(layer, rebuild=False)
     74     self._maybe_rebuild()

File ~\Desktop\TFproj\tfvenv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py:95, in Sequential.add(self, layer, rebuild)
     93         layer = origin_layer
     94 if not isinstance(layer, Layer):
---> 95     raise ValueError(
     96         "Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be "
     97         f"added to a Sequential model. Received: {layer} "
     98         f"(of type {type(layer)})"
     99     )
    100 if not self._is_layer_name_unique(layer):
    101     raise ValueError(
    102         "All layers added to a Sequential model "
    103         f"should have unique names. Name '{layer.name}' is already "
    104         "the name of a layer in this model. Update the `name` argument "
    105         "to pass a unique name."
    106     )

ValueError: Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x0000021DD8434FB0> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>)



it seems it doesn't work with hub.KerasLayer() (tensorflow_hub.keras_layer) but it needs normal layer keras.Layer (probably tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer)

Shouldn't you include hub.load ?

i've gotten this error with every code that has tf.keras in it, just had it with model = tf.keras.models.load_model as well, even tried using standard code that i know shouldn't give any errors, still did

Try installing tf_keras by running pip install tf_keras. Then import tf_keras and and use tf_keras.Sequential instead of tf.keras.Sequential as shown below:
import tf_keras

mobilenet_v2 ="https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/classification/4"
classifier_model = mobilenet_v2
IMAGE_SHAPE = (224, 224)

classifier = tf_keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(classifier_model, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,))
])

This solution is based on this comment on GitHub.

This github comment solved it for me (I'm using google colab).
The workaround is to install tensorflow 2.15.0:
pip install tensorflow==2.15.0 tensorflow-hub keras==2.15.0


I had this issue today and this comment on github solved it for me.
As per the github comment, the issue is that keras_layer.py will either use tf_keras or tf.keras depending on your keras version.
I fixed it by running pip install tf_keras and then setting the environment variable TF_USE_LEGACY_KERAS=1.

It worked for me using tf_keras instead of tf.kears. Looks like hub.KerasLayer() recognizes the tf_keras version on my machine.
